# Speeding up action with time

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

So I started learning SpriteKit and I made a simple game with a hero that jumps over blocks,
I move hero with SKAction moveByX and everything works fine. I want the speed of action to increase with time, so I want my hero to move faster and faster with time. I saw those speedBy and speedTo actions in library but I didn't understand them really well. 
Here's my Action code:

```
SKAction *moveRight = [SKAction moveByX:1.0 y:0 duration:0.004];
SKAction *foreverRight = [SKAction repeatActionForever:moveRight];
[self runAction:foreverRight];
```

Comment: Over time you should just use a smaller value for duration. This w2ill increase the time the move by is executed.

Answer (score 1):

As Seega pointed out to you, decreasing the duration time will cause the SKAction movement to be executed faster.

However in your case your your duration is already at 0.004 seconds. Decreasing this value even more would probably not cause a noticeable change. Instead you should change the moveByX value from 1.0 to something higher like 1.5 or 2.0

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the velocity property instead of use SKAction.
First you have to create a physicsbody, and after that assign a speed.

```
    self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:1];
    self.physicsBody.velocity=CGVectorMake(speed,0);
    self.physicsBody.linearDamping=0; //avoid air resistance
    self.physicsBody.affectedByGravity=NO; //avoid gravity
```

You can also use SKActions to regulate that speed, something like this

```
    SKAction* wait = [SKAction waitForDuration:1];
    SKAction* speedUp = [SKAction runBlock:^(void){
        speed+=5; //5 for example, play with numbers to see the acceleration
    }]; 
    SKAction* waitAndSpeedUp = [SKAction sequence:@[wait,speedUp]];

    SKAction* forever = [SKAction repeatActionForever:waitAndSpeedUp];

    [self runAction:forever];
```

In this case you wait 1 second and increase the speed by 5 forever

Answer (score 0):

Using an action with a duration of 0.004 is silly because there is no such duration in a SpriteKit game on an iOS device. The quickest movement you will get is over 0.016 seconds. (i.e. 1/60 seconds).

The better way to do this would be to change not the duration but the distance and do it with a duration of 0 in the update method. Something like this...

```
- (void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime
{
    // other stuff

        CGFloat pixelsPerSecond = 100 + 10 * self.gameDuration; //some function of time that means speed increases over time as the game plays.

        CGFloat pixelsMoved = pixelsPerSecond * deltaTime; //delta time is the time change between update calls.

        [self runAction:[SKAction moveByX:pixelsMoved y:0 duration:0]];

    // other stuff
}
```

This will move the character at an ever increasing speed.